# geometrical perspective of linear dependence with zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Geometrically linear dependence means that either one vector overlaps with the other or, the number of vectors is greater than the span of the vector.

So, a theorem in linear algebra says that: **"If a set S = {v1, ...., vp}  in R<sup>n</sup> contains the zero Vector, then the set is linearly dependent"**

What is the geometrical interpretation of this theorem? Since all linear transformations contain the origin anyway, How do we make sense that 0 vector being in a set of vectors make the vectors linearly dependent?

Comment: To use your terminology, the zero vector “overlaps” every vector.

Comment: @amd, The terminology comes from here: https://youtu.be/k7RM-ot2NWY